# Create And Update on a table a bulk of Objects

Tags: react-native, realm

Right now I'm trying to create and on another function update at least 4000 objects with different info.
But every time I do this my js thread completely freezes for a few seconds.

What I'm looking for is if there is an optimized way to achieve this.

Example Code:

```
realm.write(() => {
      var userInfo = realm.objects('usersInfo');

      response.message.map((obj2) => { //4000 positions 

            var foundUser = userInfo.filtered('id_server == ' + obj2.id_server);

            obj2.id = (foundUser.length) && foundUser[0].id || false;

            if (!obj2.id) {
                  obj2.id = (userInfo.length) && userInfo[(userInfo.length - 1)].id + 1 || 1;
            }

            realm.create('usersInfo', obj2, true);  //This  code puts my JS Thread from 50 FPS to -2.
      })
})
```

Realm: 2.2.6

React-Native: 0.44.1

Comment: `But every time I do this my js thread completely freezes for a few seconds.` -- Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: But I know why the code JS Thread is blocking.  
It's because I'm inserting new elements into the database.
And the desired behavior is to gather info from other developers in ways to optimize the insertion code.
I will edit and Post my code to give a start reference.